# how to make the names I record in ArrayList start with a capital letter

Tags: java

How do I make the names I record in an `ArrayList` start with a capital letter?

```
public class Main {

    public static String city() {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        ArrayList<String> names = new ArrayList<String>();
        int i = 0;
        String name;

        while (i < 50) {
            name = input.next();
            if (name.equals("end")) break;
            Character.isUpperCase(name.charAt(0)); // ????????????
            names.add(name);
            i++;
        }
        System.out.println(names);
        return city();
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With this:

```
String newName = name.substring(0, 1).toUpperCase() + name.substring(1);
```

if you want the rest of the name to be lower case:

```
String newName = name.substring(0, 1).toUpperCase() + name.substring(1).toLowerCase();
```

Answer (score 3):

You can capitalize the first letter of every `String` in the `ArrayList` by this:

```
String capitalizedName = Character.toUpperCase(name.charAt(0)).concat(name.substring(1));
```

Answer (score 1):

Can be done like this as well

```
 names.stream()
.map(str -> str.substring(0, 1).toUpperCase() + 
    str.substring(1))
.forEach(System.out::println);
```

It will be straight forward in case [`StringUtils.capitalize(..)`](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/javadocs/api-2.5/org/apache/commons/lang/StringUtils.html#capitalize%28java.lang.String%29)  from [commons-lang](http://commons.apache.org/lang/)